# WindowBuilder Design Tab blank

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I have the latest eclipse 2021-03 and installed the latest WindowBuilder Pro 1.9.6 .

Whatever I try, I can't get WindowBuilder to show elements in the Design Tab. Everything is blank as you can see in the screenshot.
[Screenshot WindowBuilder in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRUUb.png)

Does anybody know what the problem is or even fixed this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages about this.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed. Please install 1.9.7 from https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php